# How to Install Linux on my PC

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, internet

Hi i need some help to install the drivers from my pc, on Ubuntu 10.10 i just installed it, and i a newbie on Ubuntu, but i understand a bit of Windows...but i want to try ubuntu and then Maybe change to UBUNTU!!!

My hardware:

QuadCore Intel Core i7-870, 3266 MHz (24 x 136)

Asus P7P55D-E  (2 PCI, 3 PCI-E x1, 2 PCI-E x16, 4 DDR3 DIMM, Audio, Gigabit LAN, IEEE-1394)

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 480  (1536 MB)

nVIDIA HDMI @ nVIDIA GF100 - High Definition Audio Controller

VIA VT1828S @ Intel Ibex Peak PCH - High Definition Audio Controller [B-3]

DIMM1: G Skill F3-12800CL9-2GBRL    2 GB DDR3-1333 DDR3 SDRAM  (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz)  (7-7-7-20 @ 533 MHz)  (6-6-6-17 @ 457 MHz)

DIMM3: G Skill F3-12800CL9-2GBRL    2 GB DDR3-1333 DDR3 SDRAM  (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz)  (7-7-7-20 @ 533 MHz)  (6-6-6-17 @ 457 MHz)

my pc is not connected to the internet with a wire(RJ45) but with a wireless LAn Asus WL-167G-V3(wich i also whant to install if possible)

Anything would've help me :)
Cheers & Thank you!

Comment: You cannot install an OS on your CPU... Are you trying to install it on your computer (Hard disk?)

Comment: I'd suggest you to burn a LiveCD/USB, boot into it, test it, and then if you have any problems, ask some more specific questions. Generally Ubuntu is quite good at detecting HW automatically.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing the last word in your title from CPU to PC, as I assume that's what you meant :)

Comment: Since you already have Ubuntu installed, if you can check and let us know what drivers automatically loaded, we can help specifically on that. Like, Is audio, Gigabit lan and wireless etc etc..working or not working..At the moment it is quite vague to understand if really face problems on any of these, or they work fine and you just need to use them.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a dual boot system and I'm assuming you have Ubuntu installed from a CD. I also suspect that you're wireless card was not detected, hence it is unable to download updates etc.

I've been in this situation a couple of times and the best thing to do is to find a way to connect your machine to the internet through a LAN cable. This will allow Ubuntu to connect and update to latest drivers. Hopefully it will ask you if you want to enable proprietary drivers. Select YES.

Once thats done, you can go back to using your wireless network.

Comment: its cool now, im using cable Lan, im trying to install my wilress usb adapter but it's hard to make it because im still learning how to deal with Ubuntu, but ill get there ;) thank you all!!!

Cheers!